# How to see source code of android.support.v4.app.Fragment class in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm debugging a bug. If it is possible to access the source of this class, it will be helpful.

I'm thinking of setting a breakpoint or adding log statements there to help with my debugging.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac, you can press `CMD` and click on the Fragment() instantiation, for instance

```
class NotificationsFragment : Fragment() <--
```

and Android Studio will show you the source code of the Fragment class. From there you can set any breakpoint you need.

Since it is a read-only file, you cannot add any log statements.